# What will happen to uncommited and unstaged files after git reset --hard?

Tags: git, git-reset

I'm trying to understand git reset command. I have a initial commit_A containing a file file_1.

- Now I added file_2 in my working directory which I haven't
  staged. If I run `git reset --hard` now, file_2 still remains in working directory.
- But if I stage file_2 and then run `git reset --hard` ,file_2 is unstaged and also removed from working directory.

Why is file_2 removed from working directory in second case and not removed in first case ?

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, `file_2` is not tracked as you just added it to your working directory without staging or embed it into a commit.
Executing `git reset --hard` will then have no impact on these file as it's not tracked by git.

In the second case, you started tracking `file_2` (by staging it) which means that running `git reset --hard` will then [reset](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) your working directory including `file_2`, it's then removed from both your staging area and your working directory.

I would also advice you to take a deeper look at this [well explained article](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) (full of examples) on [the role of reset](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).